# How often does my HTML call a function?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in my HTML:

```
 <div >{{ getHint(us.q.hint) }}</div>
```

Can someone tell me when the function will be called? Is it called many times or just the once when us.q.hint changes value?

**Update**

I have a few answers and they're different.  Is there a way that I could make the function call only each time the value changes?

Comment: It creates watcher and and would get invoked as much time as digest loop gets executed. install [batrang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) tool and explore and observe how watchers are getting executed and how much time is getting consumed.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya - you mention it creates a watcher.  If that's the case then does the watcher not watch and only call the function when us.q.hint changes value?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `getHint` do something expensive? It may not be that bad to leave it like this if the `getHint` call is not expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many times.

Interpolations (the `{{ ... }}` construct) are evaluated during every iteration of the digest cycle. The digest cycle happens for every event that is handled by Angular, and there can be multiple iterations per digest cycle.

An interpolation creates a watcher on the interpolated expression. The digest cycle loops through all watchers and evaluates each one to detect changes that need to be applied to the view. The digest code detects changes by evaluating each expression and comparing it to the previous value. This means that every watched expression is evaluated/executed at least once during every digest cycle.

In your case, the interpolated expression is `getHint(us.q.hint)`. When that expression is evaluated, the `$scope.getHint` function is called and passed in the value of `$scope.us.q.hint`. The return value from `getHint` is compared to the previous value to determine if it has changed.

So you see, it is not the value of `$scope.us.q.hint` that is being watched, it is the value of the entire expression.

See more info on [interpolations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation), [watches](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), and [the digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

**Update for Update**

If you want your function to get called only when the argument changes, you could do it with two changes:

1. Create a watch on the value that will change and call `getHint` in the watcher.
2. Create a scope variable to hold the result of the `getHint` call and bind that to the view.

So in your controller (every watcher gets called at least once, which will initialize `$scope.hint`):

```
$scope.$watch('us.q.hint', function () {
    $scope.hint = $scope.getHint($scope.us.q.hint);
});
```

And in your view:

```
<div >{{ hint }}</div>
```

Comment: I am getting different answers here.  Each time value changes or not each time the value changes?  Is there a way that I can make it call the function only when the value changes?

Comment: @Alan I elaborated a bit. Hopefully that is clearer.

Comment: @JackA. is correct. In Angular1 change detection runs on every digest cycle (take a look at the links he provided). Digest cycle runs a minimum of 2 times for each cycle, which basically run on anything async or event-based within the context of Angular. So ng-click, ng-model, $http.get, etc will all trigger a digest cycle. If it's an expensive operation, try creating a variable like $scope.myHint and set it when us.q.hint changes through $scope.$watch('us.q.hint', function (newVal, oldVal) { $scope.myHint = getHint(newVal)}) and use {{myHint}} in your HTML instead.

Comment: @JasonAden Yes, I assume we are discussing AngularJS 1.x unless the [angular2] tag is used.

Answer (score 0):

This will be called more than one time infact as many time as your html render or page is refreshed this will not be dependent on change in value of

```
 us.q.hint
```

Comment: I am getting different answers here.  Each time value changes or not each time the value changes?

Comment: it will not dependent on wheter value changes or not it will get called it is not neecasary that if   us.q.hint change value then it get called

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your english in the last comment.

Comment: I mean that it is not compulsary for  your html to call function each tine q,hint changes its value

Answer (score -1):

yes each time us.q.hint value change it will be executed as it is being watched.

Comment: I am getting different answers here.  Each time value changes or not each time the value changes?